# Compañeros, tengo una duda con la siguiente expresión

Tags: javascript

Por favor alguien que me pueda dar claridad sobre el cuerpo del codigo: Gracias

```
   var actividadesguardadas = ((pet) => pet.actividad);
   var nameActivity = this.actividades.map(actividadesguardadas);
   return nameActivity;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a que te referis con darte claridad? que entendes que psas? que revisaste que fuera pasando? de donde sale esto?

Comment: La respuesta la consigues leyendo la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: si estas en el scope global this apunta a window. Windows.actividades no existe (no sabemos de donde sale esa propiedad) y menos podes hacer un map sobre el.

Comment: Hola @AndresGuato, para que te podamos ayudar, necesitamos más contexto, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código completo de la función, y (si no es muy largo) el del programa.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo ese fragmento forma parte de una función y en esencia recorre un arreglo de objetos y vas obteniendo la propiedad actividad del mismo. Creando un arreglo de solo actividades que es el valor que retorna. Yo lo refactorizaría de la siguiente manera:

```
const obtenerActividades = (arregloDatos = []) => {
  return arregloDatos.map(item => item.actividad); 
}    

// lo invocarías así:
let soloActividades = obtenerActividades(this.actividades);
```